# Cannot redeclare _PEAR_call_destructors()

Tags: php, apache

I totally understand, that there are lot of threads online about this issue, but I just don't seem to get it working, because a lot of them do not match with issue I'm having.

I'm integrating some custom code (written by random guy). When I run it, I get this:

> PHP Fatal error:  Cannot redeclare _PEAR_call_destructors() (previously declared in /var/www/my_project/classes/_externals/PEAR.php:773) in /usr/share/php/PEAR.php on line 777

And I understand the problem - the code includes its own `PEAR.php` with same (?) code, but earlier that the other from system includes.

So it throws me an error. How could I solve this problem? Is it possible to tell PHP to everide definitions and functions? I think that would do it.

I'm running `PHP 5.3.10-1ubuntu3.11` with `Suhosin-Patch (cli) Apache Apache/2.2.22`

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to  define your own include path with ini_set() in the code.
I haven't faced this situation yet. I found this link:

http://forums.uber.com.au/showthread.php?1851-PEAR-Fatal-error-Cannot-redeclare

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I have also get into the similar issue when i upgrade a site from prestashop 1.3 to prestashop 1.6.

I fixed it by delete all modules in the modules folder and then copy the files from the newly downloaded prestashop_x.zip modules folder.

That means some of the modules creating the problem. I haven't check it deeply. But it may give a way to analyze what is the problem.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I got the error when installing the new roundcube. The problem was likely that roundcube came with its own version of PEAR that conflicted with my debian-packaged version. This *only* manifested itself when I tried to send e-mails, but at that point, it showed up in the syslog.

I removed the `pear` and `pear-pear.php.net` folders from the `vendor` folder in my roundcube installation. The problem has not reappeared, and roundcube seems to be working fine.

Answer (score 0):

This problem will appear when you try to `set_include_path` two times in source code. In included paths, available PEAR (of course,  it also coincide).

The way to solve: Check included paths in source codes and `php.ini` by `get_include_path` function.